# Getting IPv6 TCP statistics

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, ipv6

I am trying to monitor TCP segments sent/received.

With IPv4, this is easy: either using the (old) `netstat -s` command which gives

```
...
Tcp:
    ...
    53291 segments received
    37350 segments send out
    ...
```

However, I cannot find this information for IPv6. Using `netstat -s -6` gives information about the IP6 packets, ICMP6, and UDP6, but it returns the exact same TCP information as the `netstat -s` command.

I `cat`'ed around in `/proc/net` and found `/proc/net/snmp6` which appears to be where `netstat -s -6` was getting its information, but that file has a distinct absence of TCP information.

Is TCP over IPv6 reported somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TCP statistics reported by `netstat -s` is the aggregation of TCP traffic over both IPv4 and IPv6. Which makes sense to me, since TCP is TCP, why should the underlying protocol matter? (Ok, I know about the change in the checksum field, necessitated by the different Layer 3 header.)